# laravel custom validation issue it is not working proper way some error is given and some is not given

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

this is my validation code but not given proper validation error.It is showing only these error

Special character is not allowed like \t, :, \n
GivenName is required
MiddleName is required
while maximum field is required

```
$this->validate($request,[
            'DisplayName'=>'required|max:500',
            'DisplayName'=>'regex:/(^[A-Za-z0-9]+$)+/',
            'GivenName'  => 'required|max:100',
            'MiddleName' =>'required|max:100',
            'Title'      => 'max:16',
            'Suffix'     =>'max:16',
            'FamilyName' =>'max:100'
        ],
        [
            'DisplayName.required'     => 'DisplayName is required!',
            'DisplayName.regex'        => 'Special character is not allowed like \t, :, \n ',
            'GivenName.max'            =>'GivenName is max 100 words',
            'GivenName.required'       =>'GivenName is required',
            'MiddleName.max'           =>'MiddleName is max 100 words',
            'MiddleName.required'      =>'MiddleName is required',
            'Title.max'                =>'Title is max 16 words',  
            'Suffix.max'               =>'Suffix is max 16 words',
            'FamilyName.max'           =>'FamilyName is 100 words'
        ],
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Paste your all codes and describe it as it is. And what do you mean by "while maximum field is required"

Comment: Your code is fine, what error did you get? You had a mistake in your code on the end `);`

Comment: just take a example my display name field ..in display name field have two validation  1 is required 2 is regex ok when i submit button it is not running require validation it is given regex messge.

Comment: in single field 2 custom message is not working actually that is my issue

Comment: @yogesh I answered your question. Your rule is well done BUT you need to know, specify validation rules with `regex ` separated by pipeline can lead to undesired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `regex` pattern, it may be necessary to specify rules in an array instead of using **pipe delimiters**, especially if the regular expression contains a pipe character, Like :

```
$this->validate(request(), [
    'userName' => 
        array(
            'required',
            'regex:/(^([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)?$)/u'
        )
]);
```

So your code should be :

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'DisplayName' => 
            array(
              'required',
              'max:500',
              'regex:/(^[A-Za-z0-9]+$)+/'
            ),
         'GivenName'  => 'required|max:100',
         'MiddleName' =>'required|max:100',
         'Title'      => 'max:16',
         'Suffix'     =>'max:16',
         'FamilyName' =>'max:100'
     ],
     [
         'DisplayName.required'     => 'DisplayName is required!',
         'DisplayName.regex'        => 'Special character is not allowed like \t, :, \n ',
         'GivenName.max'            =>'GivenName is max 100 words',
         'GivenName.required'       =>'GivenName is required',
         'MiddleName.max'           =>'MiddleName is max 100 words',
         'MiddleName.required'      =>'MiddleName is required',
         'Title.max'                =>'Title is max 16 words',  
         'Suffix.max'               =>'Suffix is max 16 words',
         'FamilyName.max'           =>'FamilyName is 100 words'
     ],
);
```